# Absolute value of improper integrals

Tags: integration

I have read that the following property holds for integrals where $f$ is a real function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$

|$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx| \le \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| dx$

Can this property of absolute values hold for improper integrals (i.e. integrals from $-\infty $ to +$\infty$), if $f$ satisfies certain properties (for example, continuity)? All help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it holds in that case as well, and for almost trivial reasons. Just take the limit $b\to\infty$ and $a\to -\infty$ in the first inequality (which you actually wrote incorrectly; it should be $\int_a^b$).

Comment: Note that if the integral is absolutely convergent, we can do a change of variable to make $a,b$ bounded, e.g. $\tanh$. You only have to discuss the cases of divergence of LHS (because RHS being $\nearrow$ it can only diverge to $+\infty$ and obsviously everything is $\le$ to that).